# cannot start application if not on correct path

Tags: command-line, startup, startup-applications, execute-command

I have the following app "System monitor indicator" and I want to make it start on boot up. So I am trying to find whats the name of the app to call it from the terminal, I find the "exe" at /usr/share/applications and the name is indicator-monitor.desktop

If I try

```
sudo /usr/share/applications/indicator-monitor
```

it says command not found

If I remove the sudo it says permission denied.

however when I do

```
cd /usr/share/applications && sudo indicator-monitor
```

it executes fine.

If I put the above on the start up command it doesn't open. 
Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `/usr/share/applications` is not the correct path for binary executables. And `indicator-monitor` is the **command** that is searched in directories set in $PATH environment variable. There are generally 6-8 locations divided by colon sign: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`.

Answer (score 1):

You are going wrong. **/usr/share/applications** contains launcher file(config file), not executable file. You can't run .desktop file by sudo command. Instead of you should run executable file.

```
sudo /usr/share/applications/indicator-monitor
```

Why it's not working? There is no file named indicator-monitor but indicator-monitor.desktop.

```
cd /usr/share/applications && sudo indicator-monitor
```

Why it's working? your first command will go to applications folder. It's ok. But next command will run indicator-monitor (executable file from env path), not from current directory. Current directory needs ./ prefix.

How to find where is executable file? run the following command with application name

```
which indicator-monitor
```

Check out the env path run the following command
echo $PATH

printed directories are accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Basically the same answer as mine, but better structured. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not running anything in `/usr/share/applications/`. By `cd`'in into there doesn't make it run off there from a `.desktop` file. Instead, it just goes off your `PATH`s. You are just running the global `indicator-monitor` from a global `PATH`.

It doesn't make any difference as to what your current working directory is. Just

```
sudo indicator-monitor
```

in anywhere will result in the same.

And you see a "command not found" error because there's no such file like `/usr/share/applications/indicator-monitor`. Run

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/indicator-monitor
```

to verify.

A `.desktop` file is meant to run from the GUI, being displayed as an icon and to be run by clicking it. See the contents of the file for what is actually happening (just a text file!).

Comment: but the file exists I can see it in /usr/share/applications, I will have to run this in a few hours when i get to my pc. Thnx tho

Comment: @drakoumelitos No. There's only `indicator-monitor.desktop` in there, not `indicator-monitor`.

Comment: so within the .desktop there will be the command needed to execute it through the terminal?

Comment: @drakoumelitos Yes. It has a line starting with `Exec=` usually showing what command will be run in the background if you click an icon. However, this *could* take more parameters than you use on the command line specified by the `.desktop` file standard.

Comment: aha! ok then thnx a lot i guess my problem was finding the actual name of the app